# How to deal with questions that are just pointing to a bug report?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145724/raspi-v4l4j-driver-does-not-start-again-after-the-first-run):

[image]

and that question basically says:

*there is a bug report somewhere with all relevant information; does somebody here know how to fix this?*

So - what is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: I'd vote to close as off topic: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. ` Emphasis on **in the question itself**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal in two ways with such kind of questions:

1. close it with the mark off topic as shown in the picture.

[image]

2. You can leave the comment that it is general issue which is still in progress. So that he can try to solve it or debug it. As we all can not produce same condition on our system.

Its your choice what you want to do.